# How to select a string entry in a listbox by a given string without looping?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

In WPF there's no listbox.findString.

Comment: Is that a `question` or a `statement`?

Comment: title is a question, content is a statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say we have a listbox:

```
ListBox b = new ListBox();
```

Then you could use LINQ:

```
        int index = b.Items.IndexOf((
            from ListBoxItem a in b.Items
            where a.Content.ToString() == "something"
            select a).First());
```

Or you can use foreach:

```
        foreach (ListBoxItem lbi in b.Items)
        {
            if (lbi.Content is string && (string)lbi.Content == "something")
            {
                index = b.Items.IndexOf(lbi);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Using LINQ to set the string to `something`? Your code is equivalent to `string s = "something"`.

Comment: there will be a loop either way, findString has a loop LINQ will have a loop, so the foreach approach will do the same thing

Comment: this comparsion `a.Content == "something"` will use Object.ReferenceEquals, so likely the statement will fall with `InvalidOperationException`. You need to cast `a.Content` to `string` or call `ToString()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var entries = listBox.Items.Where(item => item.ToString() == "something");
```

Answer (score 0):

In most scenarios, you want to bind the ListBox's ItemsSource to an actual collection in your code that implements IEnumerable, then use the .Where().First() statement to find the first occurence of your string, like this:

```
List<string> lstb = new List<string>() { "StringA", "StringB", "StringC" };
string stringC = lstb.Where(s => s == "StringC").First();
```

Then if you want to programmatically select the item in your list:

```
yourListBox.SelectedItem = stringC;
```

However I strongly suggest you take the time to learn about databinding and the MVVM model which simplifies interaction with WPF controls by a lot.